# Tabris: Does the Tabris SDK consider touch events?

Tags: java, mobile

I am working on a small demo using the Tabris SDK. It essentially is based on one of the entrypoints of the Tabris demos. I created a drawing widget and added a `TouchListener` like in the following code snippet:

```
canvas.addTouchListener( new TouchListener() {

  public void touch( TouchEvent e ) 
  {
    Point point = new Point(e.x,e.y);
    mPointList.add( point );
    canvas.redraw();
  }
} );
```

where `canvas` is a `ClientCanvas` from the Tabris SDK.
However the `touch`-method of the `TouchListener` is never called.

Is the `TouchListener` supported at all in the current Tabris SDK ( I am using ver 0.8.0)?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TouchListener is not yet supported (needs to be implemented in RAP first).
You need to use the MouseListener.